# PHP's __call() and __callStatic() function equivalent in c#

Tags: c#, php, magic-methods

I am trying to learn c# recently. I am new to it. Are there any magic functions-like constructs in c# like in php. Specifically, what are the equivalent functions for __call() and __callStatic() functions in c# that are present in php...

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry mate, but at this point in time there is no like for like equivalent in C#.

I personally wish the PHP magic methods were in C#. It would provide developers a big and beautiful way, to open up to a whole new variety of design patterns.

But Alas, most people in the development space are trying to do the opposite. Trying to crack down on designs or patterns which they consider to be "anti-patterns" and forcing *aghem* I mean "educating", us on how best to program.

There is some merit in it, but not always. Every solution shouldn't always be designed in the same way.

A great modern example of this "education" is that everything must be DI (Dependency Injected) and have an underlying interface. Not to mentioned forced patterns like MVC, MVVM etc. Anything outside of these mainstream ideas are often considered heresy.

Answer (score 1):

There is a possibility. Inherit your class from DynamicObject and override the method `TryInvokeMember`. With the example below you will have a chance to invoke unexistent methods as a `__call` php overload or access private members.

Here's an example

```
        class Api : DynamicObject
        {
            public override bool TryInvokeMember(InvokeMemberBinder binder, object[] args, out object result)
            {
                if ((int)args[0] == 55)
                    result = "Match";
                else
                    result = "No match";
                return true;

                // or return the result of the original method which can be an
                // exception if the method does not exist

                // return base.TryInvokeMember(binder, args, out result);
            }
        }
```

Given the previous example, use it as follows

```
dynamic api   = new Api();
string result = api.get_account_id(55);
```

I Hope this help